# ¿como mostrar una animación en donde la imagenes salgan de la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quisiera que las nubes despejen la pantalla saliendo de ella y no regresen al mismo lugar.

quiero que al iniciar mi web se muestren nubes que se van hacia los lados y desaparecen de la pantalla, lo que pretendo lograr es un efecto o transición algo así como cuando se inicia el juego clash of clans en donde las nubes cubren casi toda la pantalla y luego la despejan para mostrar el contenido.

En este ejemplo se muestra como hay algunas nubes que se mueven hacia los lados pero no salen de la pantalla.

quiero que al iniciar mi web se muestren nubes que se van hacia los lados y desaparecen de la pantalla, lo que pretendo lograr es un efecto  donde las nubes cubren casi toda la pantalla y luego la despejan para mostrar el contenido.

```js
src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hm5cv6ydshdu77l/prefixfree.min.js"
```

```css
body {background-color:#f9f9f9;}

#cielo {left:35%; position:absolute;}

/* Declaracion de bg y animacion de las nubes */
.nube1, .nube2, .nube3, .nube4 { background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t298wyf035rfbwf/csg-5249a56c1c5d9.png) no-repeat top left;
    animation: levitacion 1.1s infinite linear alternate, levitacion-x 3s infinite linear alternate;
}
.nube1{ background-position: 0 0; width: 82px; height: 90px; } 
.nube2{ background-position: -132px 0; width: 159px; height: 90px; } 
.nube3{ background-position: -341px 0; width: 287px; height: 62px; } 
.nube4{ background-position: -678px 0; width: 94px; height: 81px; } 
.sol { background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t298wyf035rfbwf/csg-5249a56c1c5d9.png) no-repeat top left; background-position: -822px 0; width: 256px; height: 256px;} 

/* Declaracion de despejes */
.n-izq { animation: despejarse-n-izq 2s infinite ease-in-out alternate-reverse; animation-play-state: paused;}
.n-der { animation: despejarse-n-der 2s infinite ease-in-out alternate; animation-play-state: paused;}

/* Al hacer hover en sol, despejar */
.sol:hover .n-izq, .sol:hover .n-der {animation-play-state: running;}

/* Posicionamiento */
.n-izq, .n-der, .sol, .nube {position:absolute;}
.n-izq {left:50px;top:80px; z-index:10; width:300px; margin-left: -88px; }
.sol {left:100px; }
.n-der {top:100px; left:230px; z-index:10; margin-left: -92px;}
.nube1 {left:60px; margin-top:-50px; }
.nube4 {margin-top:-50px;}

/* Levitacion Vertical */
@keyframes levitacion { 
    0% { top: 8px; } 
    100% { top:3px; } 
} 
@-moz-keyframes levitacion { 
    0% { top: 8px; } 
    100% { top:3px; } 
} 
@-ms-keyframes levitacion { 
    0% { top: 5px; } 
    100% { top:3px; } 
} 
@-o-keyframes levitacion { 
    0% { top: 5px; } 
    100% { top:3px; } 
} 

/*Levitacion Horizontal*/
@keyframes levitacion-x { 
    0% { left: 8px; } 
    100% { left:3px; } 
} 
@-moz-keyframes levitacion-x { 
    0% { left: 8px; } 
    100% { left:3px; } 
} 
@-ms-keyframes levitacion-x { 
    0% { left: 8px; } 
    100% { left:3px; } 
} 
@-o-keyframes levitacion-x { 
    0% { left: 8px; } 
    100% { left:3px; } 
} 

/* Despejar nubes izquierdas */
@keyframes despejarse-n-izq  { 
    0% { left: 0px; } 
    100% { left:50px; } 
} 
@-moz-keyframes despejarse-n-izq  { 
    0% { left: 0px; } 
    100% { left:50px; } 
} 
@-ms-keyframes despejarse-n-izq  { 
    0% { left: 0px; } 
    100% { left:50px; } 
} 
@-o-keyframes despejarse-n-izq  { 
    0% { left: 0px; } 
    100% { left:50px; } 
} 


/*Despejar nubes derechas */
@keyframes despejarse-n-der  { 
    0% { left: 230px; } 
    100% { left:300px; } 
} 
@-moz-keyframes despejarse-n-der  { 
    0% { left: 230px; } 
    100% { left:300px; } 
} 
@-ms-keyframes despejarse-n-der  { 
    0% { left: 230px; } 
    100% { left:300px; } 
} 
@-o-keyframes despejarse-n-der  { 
    0% { left: 230px; } 
    100% { left:300px; } 
}
```

```html
<div id="cielo">

  <div class="sol">
    <div class="n-izq">
      <div class="nube1"></div>
      <div class="nube2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="n-der">
      <div class="nube3"></div>
      <div class="nube4"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es declarar donde quieres que estén las nubes al final de la animación (fuera de la pantalla)

```css
body {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

#cielo {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150%;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Declaracion de bg y animacion de las nubes */

.nube1,
.nube2,
.nube3,
.nube4 {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t298wyf035rfbwf/csg-5249a56c1c5d9.png) no-repeat top left;
  animation: levitacion 1.1s linear alternate, levitacion-x 3s linear alternate;
}

.nube1 {
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 82px;
  height: 90px;
}

.nube2 {
  background-position: -132px 0;
  width: 159px;
  height: 90px;
}

.nube3 {
  background-position: -341px 0;
  width: 287px;
  height: 62px;
}

.nube4 {
  background-position: -678px 0;
  width: 94px;
  height: 81px;
}

.sol {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t298wyf035rfbwf/csg-5249a56c1c5d9.png) no-repeat top left;
  background-position: -822px 0;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Declaracion de despejes */

.n-izq {
  animation: despejarse-n-izq 2s ease-in-out alternate-reverse;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.n-der {
  animation: despejarse-n-der 2s ease-in-out alternate;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}


/* Al hacer hover en sol, despejar */

.sol:hover .n-izq,
.sol:hover .n-der {
  animation-play-state: running;
}


/* Posicionamiento */

.n-izq,
.n-der,
.sol,
.nube {
  position: absolute;
}

.n-izq {
  left: -1050px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -88px;
}

.n-der {
  top: 100px;
  left: 1050px;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: -92px;
}

.nube1 {
  left: 60px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.nube4 {
  margin-top: -50px;
}


/* Levitacion Vertical */

@keyframes levitacion {
  0% {
    top: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 3px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes levitacion {
  0% {
    top: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 3px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes levitacion {
  0% {
    top: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 3px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes levitacion {
  0% {
    top: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 3px;
  }
}


/*Levitacion Horizontal*/

@keyframes levitacion-x {
  0% {
    left: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 3px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes levitacion-x {
  0% {
    left: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 3px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes levitacion-x {
  0% {
    left: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 3px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes levitacion-x {
  0% {
    left: 8px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 3px;
  }
}


/* Despejar nubes izquierdas */

@keyframes despejarse-n-izq {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 10%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes despejarse-n-izq {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 10%;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes despejarse-n-izq {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 10%;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes despejarse-n-izq {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 10%;
  }
}


/*Despejar nubes derechas */

@keyframes despejarse-n-der {
  0% {
    left: 230px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 1000px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes despejarse-n-der {
  0% {
    left: 230px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 1000px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes despejarse-n-der {
  0% {
    left: 230px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 1000px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes despejarse-n-der {
  0% {
    left: 230px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cielo">

  <div class="sol">
    <div class="n-izq">
      <div class="nube1"></div>
      <div class="nube2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="n-der">
      <div class="nube3"></div>
      <div class="nube4"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Espero te sirva